# C# web request method with url and process the stream

Tags: c#

How would you use this web request method?:

```
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Process the stream
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError &&
                ex.Response != null)
            {
                var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    // Do something
                }
                else
                {
                    // Do something else
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Do something else
            }
        }
    }
```

I found the above code on a website and I'm not sure what process the stream means or where you put the url :ex: http://www.google.com I prefer to use this code instead but I can't get else statements to work with it, and that is what I need.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(String.Format("URL", hashe));
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.ToString().Contains("404"))
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would replace `uri` with the address, or create a string variable named uri and provide it with the address.

eg.

```
string uri = "http://www.google.se"
```

But, you are much better off using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx).

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString ("http://www.google.se");
```